# Justification of truth table of conditional statement if $p$ then $q$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I have gone through various sites but i can't understand the justification for the truth table of "If $p$ then $q$". Is it accepted by the mathematicians without any proof or justification?
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
p & q & p\rightarrow q \\ \hline
T & T & T \\
T & F & F \\
F & T & T \\
F & F & T 
\end{array}
Last two values of truth table seems a bit confusing how is true?

Comment: You can find many many similar questions on this site, like: [truth-table-fo $p \to q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1732021/truth-table-for-p-implies-q) and [understanding-implication-in-logic-truth-tables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368138/understanding-implication-in-logic-truth-tables-excerpt-from-textbook)

Comment: that last two values seems confusing. i have read that article too........ Suppose p=it is cloudy outside,q=it is raining outside then according to p->q if it is cloudy outside then it is raining outside how does this statement justify this

Comment: there is no justification; it is the definition of "if.... then....".

Comment: See also the post: [implications and ordinary language](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718925/implications-and-ordinary-language) about a "reasonable" justification.

Comment: why there is no justification for this?

Comment: See also the post: [conditional statements "only if"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617562/conditional-statements-only-if).

Comment: See also the post: [on the truth value of implication connective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970552/on-the-truth-value-of-implication-connective).

Comment: Stupid example: For integers $a,b,c$ we sure want $((a=b) \Longrightarrow (ac=bc))$ to be true. For $a\neq b$ and $c\in\{0,1\}$ this justifies the last two rows of your truth table.

Comment: See also the post: [how to interpret material conditional and explain it to freshmen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232309/how-to-interpret-material-conditional-and-explain-it-to-freshmen).

Comment: See also the post: [in classical logic why is $p \rightarrow q$ true if p is false and q is true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70736/in-classical-logic-why-is-p-rightarrow-q-true-if-p-is-false-and-q-is-tr).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Can we have more?

Comment: Thanks @MauroAllegranza for everything

Comment: I know this table as the _definition_ of the implication.

Comment: See also: [Logical Conditional Rationale](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208612/logical-conditional-truth-table-rationale)

Answer (score 1):

There are 16 possible truth tables for two binary variables $p$ and $q$ that take the values $T$ or $F$.

Assuming that we want:

I. $p = T$, $q = T$ and $p \implies q = T$

II. $p = T$, $q = F$ and $p \implies q = F$

we have that from the 16 possible truth tables only these 4 comply with conditions I and II:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
p & q & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
T & T & T & T & T & T\\
T & F & F & F & F & F\\
F & T & F & T & F & T\\
F & F & F & F & T & T\\
\end{array}

The truth table $1$ corresponds to the truth table of $p \land q$ so we discard that this table is suitable for $p \implies q$.

The truth table $2$ corresponds to $q$ so we discard that this table is suitable for $p \implies q$.

The truth table $3$ corresponds to the truth table of $p \Longleftrightarrow q$ so we discard that this table is suitable for $p \implies q$.

Therefore table $4$ is the only truth table suitable for $p \implies q$ if we think that conditions I and II must be fulfill and $p$ and $q$ are two binary variables that take the values $T$ or $F$.

That is the justification for the truth table of $p \implies q$.

Answer (score 0):

For the third when $p$ is false prove $p\to q$ by contradiction.
So accept $p$ and assume $\neg q$.
As $\neg p$ is true, $p$ and $\neg p$ are a contradiction.
Thus the assumption $\neg q$ is false. 
This proves $p \to q$ when p is false.

The fourth is simular.

Answer (score 0):

You can memorise easily it:
$$a \rightarrow b = \overline a \lor b$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/923917)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos This rule helps to understand why truth table of this function is that.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \left( p \implies q \right) \equiv \mbox{“p implies q”}  \equiv \mbox{“if p then q”} $$

So if the statement "$p \implies q$" holds, we have:

- If $p$ is true then the statement tells us $q$ must be true.
- If $p$ is false then the statement does not tell us anything about $q$.

The only way to prove the statement "$p \implies q$" is *wrong* is to show that $p$ holds but $q$ does not. That is why the truth table only indicates the statement is "false/wrong" in that one row.